# What are the arguments of a string concatenation called?

Tags: terminology

In real addition, (for example 3 + 7), the first argument is called the "augend", and the second argument is called the "addend".

In concatenating the string "ab" with "abb", to form the string "ababb", are there commonly-used names for the arguments?

I'm asking this from the viewpoint of a software engineer and am after terms for documentation of the concatenation process and wasn't quite content with "string1" and "string2".

Comment: Nobody really calls the arguments of addition the augend and the addend.  Maybe they did in 1874.  Just call the arguments of the concatenation the arguments; there's no need to dig up obscure or obsolete terminology for something simple.

Comment: I'd also say operands.

Comment: This would probably be a better fit for programmers.se. At any rate, best practice is to name the strings something related to what their function is

Comment: Prefix and suffix?

Comment: Left part and right part?

Comment: string1 and string2 seem fine to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would call them "concatenands", because that seems the most logical to me. But I have a hunch you wouldn't find that word in a dictionary.

Comment: I'm giving you the accepted answer as you tried to help instead of chastising me for using "obscure/obsolete" terms. Can you think of a way to differentiate them so it's clear that one comes before the other, and it's a non-commutative operation?

Comment: You could call them the "preconcatenand" and "postconcatenand" (possibly hyphenating). This is inspired by matrix multiplication (which is also in general non-commutative), wherein we talk about "pre-multiplying" and "post-multiplying" by a matrix.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was after ~8 months ago! I'll keep these terms in mind for future.